# Why closing dictionary in PostScript?

Tags: memory, stack-overflow, postscript

`PostScript` books always suggest to carefully handle dictionaries. Separate user dictionaries and keep them small, close dictionary when it is no longer needed, avoid overloading global dictionary, etc.

However, I think, these instructions back to old ages where there were severe hardware limitation for memory. Closing a dictionary to free memory. The memory a PS script needs were probably comparable with the machine available memory. In modern time, the memory needed for a heavy `PostScript` task (e.g. long document or complicated drawing) is much lesser than the machine memory, and closing a dictionary with hundreds or even thousands of elements should have no significant effect on the machine performance.

Correct me if I'm wrong! Consider that we put everything in one dictionary or global dictionary; does it have a negative impact on the PostScript performance?

Does it still beneficial (from performance point of view, not ease of coding) to separate dictionary, and more importantly close them when not needed? Or it just frees a tiny fraction of memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The memory and performance issues here are almost entirely separate.

Level-1 Postscript describes only one way to "free" memory: by `restore`-ing a previously `save`-d memory state. Level-2 (and beyond) Postscript incorporates garbage collection, so memory is available to be freed when there are no accessible references to it. Garbage collection can be disabled to reduce performance overhead (this is necessary for profiling code for speed), but of course your memory consumption is likely to increase unless you're using `save` and `restore` appropriately.

The inclusion of garbage collection makes it appropriate to add automatically-expanding dictionaries, and they did. But there's a performance cost: allocating a larger dictionary and rehashing all the keys. So if it's easy to predict the maximum size of a dictionary, you can save some of this time by creating a big-enough dictionary in the first place. You may be able to get a further speed increase by making your dictionaries twice the maximum size, as this should reduce hash collisions.

And performance is adversely affected by having extra dictionaries on the dictstack (if you don't *need* them). Since systemdict (where all the operators are) is always the bottom entry on the stack, all lookups for operator-names will search (unsuccessfully) each dictionary that's in the way before reaching systemdict.

The increase in the memory-size and processing-power of desktop computer makes these concerns somewhat less *necessary* (since you can ignore them and still have a program that "works"), but they are still *useful* (especially as your programs become larger and more complex).

A very good resource for this kind of info is Adobe's "green book" which is devoted to strategies of organizing your programs for size or speed (sometimes both).

---

I just had a crazy idea. There may be a way to get *both!* Suppose you pack your dictionary exactly to capacity (to use minimal memory), then in a critical section add one more element (forcing the dict to expand), but bracket the section with `save` and `restore`?

```
4 dict begin
/x 5 def
/y 7 def
/z 9 def
/t 12 def
currentdict end

%critical section
begin /save save def
    %Do something critical
save end restore
```

Of course this discards any updates to the dict, so if you need these updated entries, you'll have to make a copy to expand (after the save, so restore will destroy it), and copy the desired entries back into the original. And of course this is quite a bit of extra overhead; so the code that needs this trick will have to be *damned critical*. :)

Answer (score 2):

You are wrong!

First, *one* global dictionary doesn't work for everything. Some of the PostScript language operators expect certain dictionaries (including their names) to exist. So these you have to keep.

Second, it has also a performance and speed effect, not just memory consumption.

Third, it is always a good idea for a programmer to keep his code tidy and organized.

Fourth, you seem to talk about 'machines' that are (current) Personal Computer models or bigger. You do not seem to have embedded systems and their OS in mind (like many smaller PostScript printers do use).

Fifth, you seem to forget that in a PostScript (or any) program you can have loops... and any 'tiny fraction of memory' leaks can have huge effects if one leak adds to the next.

Sixth, you seem to be unaware of a certain type of error conditions and their return that are part of the language spec, which can be triggered by having the wrong items on the respective 'stack'.

Seventh, .... OK, I stop now before I start a real rant :-)